# CXF code first webservice is creating wsdl with xs:element form="unqualified" not picking up namespace

Tags: wsdl, annotations, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

I'm creating webservices with CXF using the code first approach.
I want to use namespaces, and therefore **elementFormDefault** is set to **true**.
The WSDL is fine, except for the elements embedded in the complextypes, i get following xs:element having a **form="unqualified"** tag. But I want to get rid of the **form=unqualified** tag

```xml
<xs:element form="unqualified" name="LikeSearch" type="xs:boolean"/>
```

My package-info.java looks like this:

```java
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace="http://registry.erpel.at",
   attributeFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
   elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
   package at.erpel.registry.services.webservice;
```

The Java endpoint looks like this:

```java
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://registry.erpel.at", name="CompanyEndpoint")
public interface CompanyEndpoint {
    List<Company> findCompanies(
        @WebParam(name = "FindCompaniesRequest") @XmlElement(required=true) FindCompaniesRequest findCompaniesRequest)
        throws ServiceFault ;
```

This is the FindCompaniesRequest:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "FindCompaniesRequest")
public class FindCompaniesRequest extends AbstractRequestType implements Serializable
{
   @XmlElement(name = "LikeSearch", required = true)
   protected boolean likeSearch;
   ...
}
```

And finally the WSDL:

```xml
<xs:complexType name="FindCompaniesRequest">
   <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="tns:AbstractRequestType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element form="unqualified" name="LikeSearch" type="xs:boolean"/>
```

What I want, is to get rid of the **form="unqualified"** tag

The only solution I have found so far is adding the namespace attribute to every single XMLElement:

```java
 @XmlElement(name = "LikeSearch", required = true, namespace="http://registry.erpel.at")
 protected boolean likeSearch;
```

But I want the child elements just to pick up the namespace from the parent elements. I have tried adding the namespace attribute to the @XMLRootElement annotation, to the @WebParam annotation, and to the @XmlElement annotation in the method description, but without any success.

Anyone knows how to get this working?

Comment: What package is `FindCompaniesRequest` in? If it's not `at.erpel.registry.services.webservice`, that's your problem right there. Also, what package is `CompanyEndpoint` in?

Comment: CompanyEndpoint is in at.erpel.registry.services.webservice and FindCompaniesRequest is in at.erpel.registry.services.entities.request
So they both have to be in the same package then? or is there a different solution?

Comment: Thanks to Donal I have found the solution,

I have to put a **package-info.java** into **each package** containing classes being used for generating the WSDL. In my case, I also had to put it into the package of FindCompaniesRequest!

Thanks a lot Donal!

P.S. I can't answer the question right now, because it's my first one and the system needs me to wait for 7 more hours, Donal, maybe you want to answer for me ;) thx

Comment: It was as simple as that? OK, converted it to an answer. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `package-info.java` file can only declare JAXB defaults for the classes in the same package; you've got to put one in *each* package that gets tooled into doing class generation (or define a whole lot more attributes of your annotations, which isn't much fun).

Fortunately, this is pretty much cut-n-paste coding. Just copy a single package info file around and tweak it if you want the namespace to change.

Comment: I have also added package-info.java with `elementFormDefault=javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED` But in my responses I am getting an unqualified name space.