# CXF : default wsdl path

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, tomcat7, cxf

I run a soap webservice with Tomcat7 and cxf 3.2.1 (on windows 7), if I add a wsdllocation into my cxf-servlet.xml file, I have some errors but without this attribute, cxf found a correct wsdl and my service works fine and it's not exactly My wsdl. 
It's cool, but how ? Does CXF generate wsdl on runtime ? I can't find any information about "default wsdl" in the documentation... 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after all, found the answer: Yes, CXF generate a default wsdl at runtime. If anyone come from Axis 1.x SOAP definitions, you must add a package-info.java into your API package to have a "elementFormDefault=qualified" into the wsdl types definition (some problems with different clients) see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777136/cxf-code-first-webservice-is-creating-wsdl-with-xselement-form-unqualified-no#comment11746545_6778386)

If you want to deploy a wsdl, add wsdlLocation into your servlet.xml/jaxws:endpoint definition :

```
<jaxws:endpoint xmlns:tns="http://my.service.com" 
    wsdlLocation="/wsdl/MyServiceImpl.wsdl" > 
   <!-- some configuration here -->
</jaxws>
```

Root folder is your deployment point.